# How do you make one generic select method for your DAL?

Tags: design-patterns, oop, poco

**Scenario**

You have an Assembly for Data Transfer Objects containing 10 classes that exactly represent 10 tables in your database.
You generate / build a DAL layer that has methods like -

```
  DTOForTable1[] GetDataFromTable1();
  DTOForTable2[] GetDataFromTable2();
```

and so on....

**Question**

How do I make a method that hides the numerous methods to get data from each table from the client code? The method I would want for example in service or business layer could look like-

```
SomeGenericDTO[] GetDataFromTable(TableTypeEnum tableTypeEnum);
```

1. How do I do this ? Is this even possible ?
2. If yes for (1), is it a good practice ?
3. If yes for (1) and (2) does this simplifies or complicate design ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please comment if you decide to downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define it like:

```
T[] GetDataFromTable1<T>() where T:IDto
{
   // you can know the table with the type of T
}
```

That said, I would rather either have the different methods or even classes to work with it. I use the repository pattern instead, I suggest to look for info on it.

Comment: I have read about Repository pattern but I dont think i understand it fully. Can you recommend some link ?

Comment: In "Domain-Driven Design" by Eric Evans, chapter 6 contains info about the Repository pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how my DAL does it:

```
List<entity> customers = SQL.Read(new SearchCriteria(), new Customers());
```

To perform joins:

```
List<entity> customers = SQL.Read(new SearchCriteria(), new Customers(new Orders(new OrderDetails())));
```

The DTO class itself determines which table to access and its properties determine which columns to retrieve.

I can't answer if it is a best or good practice. It is the practice that has been working for me for a long time. There are no extraneous methods such as "GetById", "GetAll", etc.

Comment: This is very intersting ! Can you provide some link or sample ??

Answer (score 1):

It's very common these days to implement your concrete table classes as inheriting an abstract table-access class.  The abstract class has generic methods to query a table.  Each concrete class can declare *which* corresponding database table (also perhaps columns and inter-table relationships).

Design patterns that help include [ActiveRecord](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) and [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html).